# Microsoft Test Manager from Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-test-manager

Anyone know the OS requirements for this? The actual System Requirements mention Windows 7 but after spending the time installing and configuring and finally get it up and running, went to the Testing Center and I get this message.

"The Test Management features are not supported on Windows Home Premium."

I now have to upgrade my Windows but I want to be sure what version is required

Comment: Sorry I don't know for certain. But I suspect business or ultimate editions. This is a really interesting observation, considering I run home premium on my laptop.

Comment: Maybe it's in the way it needs to connect to TFS ...

Comment: I can connect to TFS  inside Visual Studio to access Source Control and get the bugs but I can't get into the Test Manager, just going to install Ultimate.. sucks since I dont really want to redo my PC again

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 Home and Home Premium are not able to join a Windows Server domain. You can check this [comparison chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart) for more details.